# I want to calculate data in jtable but i have a error [Java]

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to multiply column 3 with column 4, and display it on the first line, but when I add the data in the next line, when doing the calculation again and display it on the second line, the data on the first line changes. This is my code, is there something wrong?

```
public int getCost() {
     int row = showTrans.getRowCount();
     int col = showTrans.getColumnCount();
     int cost;

     for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        cost = Integer.parseInt(showTrans.getValueAt(i, 3).toString()) * 
               Integer.parseInt(showTrans.getValueAt(i, 4).toString());  

        String totalCost = String.valueOf(cost);
        model.setValueAt(totalCost, i, 4);           
     }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `model.setValueAt(totalCost, i, 4);` you are set value to column 4, it's override the old value

Comment: But I want to show it back on that row and column

Comment: What's the point of the loop?  You seem to have the `row` which needs to be updated, why update the other rows? Perhaps you should provide runnable example of your problem, it will help provide more context to your question

Comment: this that error,, https://youtu.be/6YvkSevR92g please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are reusing column 4 for both cost and the total.

The first time it works because the cost is correct (total = 9460000), but the second time the cost is wrong because column 4 is now the total. As a result, it multiplies the quantity by the total cost (total = 9460000 * 2 = 18920000)

You need to use a new column for the total and everything should be fine.